# Turn one compound view function into two view functions

Tags: django, django-views

How would I break the following view function into two: one for the `Add` action and one for the `Delete` action.

```
# in urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('myproject.views',
url(r'^profile/edit/education/$', 'edit_education', name='edit_education'),)

# in views.py
@login_required
def edit_education(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'Delete' in request.POST.values():
            profile.educations.remove(Education.objects.get(id=education_id))
            return redirect('edit_education')
        if 'Add School' in request.POST.values():
            form = EducationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() and request.POST['school']:
                form.save()
                return redirect('edit_education')
   else:
       form = EducationForm()
   return render_to_response('userprofile/edit_education.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What changes would I need to make in these two files to break the view into two separate functions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? That code is fine - compact and self-explanatory.

Splitting it up would require not only changes in the view, but (obviously) changes in the form template so that `delete` would post somewhere different from `add`. There's no easy way of doing that, other than having two separate `<form>`s, or using some Javascript to change the form's `action` depending on which button you press. Doesn't seem like it's worth it.